# How to convert string to color?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to convert string to color because color come dynamically as a string.

Error said :

> Cannot implicity convert string to Xamarin.Form.Color

```
string BackgroundColor = (string)testData["Views"][index][name][i]["BackgroundColor"];

gridLayout.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;//Error
```

Comment: What format is the string in exactly?

Comment: Check the official documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Color/#Public_Methods

Comment: BackgroundColor is a variable that take value from json file

Comment: But what is the content of the variable? That's what is important here. For example is it a HTML style value like `#ffff00` or a colour name like `Green` or even some other weird text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose your string is a hex value of the color you want to apply. If so you must parse it as a color. The `.setBackground` method and `BackgroundColor` property accepts a color object.

To parse it, use the `Color` class which contains `FromHex` method.

`Color.FromHex("#FFF");`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Xamarin.Forms.ColorTypeConverter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ColorTypeConverter/).

This method: `ConvertFrom`

Example from link:

```
var converter = new ColorTypeConverter ();
Assert.True (converter.CanConvertFrom (typeof(string)));
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Blue, converter.ConvertFrom ("Color.Blue"));
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Blue, converter.ConvertFrom ("Blue"));
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Blue, converter.ConvertFrom ("#0000ff"));
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Default, converter.ConvertFrom ("Color.Default"));
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Accent, converter.ConvertFrom ("Accent"));
var hotpink = Color.FromHex ("#FF69B4");
Color.Accent = hotpink;
Assert.AreEqual (Color.Accent, converter.ConvertFrom ("Accent"));
```

Comment: This is a link only answer which is strongly discouraged here.

Comment: while this answers the question, it is preferable to copy some relevant examples / code here, as the link can become dead.

Comment: @DavidG @ Pac0 Improved

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to color using ColorTypeConverter

```
var converter = new ColorTypeConverter ();
gridLayout.BackgroundColor = converter.ConvertFrom ("Color.Blue");
gridLayout.BackgroundColor = converter.ConvertFrom ("Blue");
gridLayout.BackgroundColor = converter.ConvertFrom ("#0000ff");
```

Hope this helps